# NodeJS/ Express/EJS: Cannot get length of JSON Array rendered from NodeJS in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, ejs

Firstly, I would like to mention that I'm able to get the correct length of data if I put the for loop inside EJS, but the same thing doesn't work in Javascript.

My code in ejs file:

```
<% for(var i=0; i< arr.length; i++){ %>
      TESTING
<% } %>
```

This will display TESTING for `3 times`, which is correct. However, when I run the loop in Javascript, it gives me 40++ outputs.

My code in same ejs file:

```
<script>
var newArr = "<%- arr%>";

 for(var i=0; i< newArr.length; i++){ 
      $(document).ready(function() {
           setData();
      });
 }

 function setData(){
     var box = document.getElementById('list-box');
     const para = document.createElement('p');
     para.innerHTML = `<input type="button" value="Test">`
     box.appendChild(para);
 }
</script>
```

Over 40 paragraphs are appended here...I have no idea why the length can be different (there is no error at all). May someone teach me on method of getting length in javascript?

Comment: `newArr` is a string and `newArr.length` is the number of characters. Remove the quotes: `var newArr = <%- arr%>;`

Comment: I see, how should I get the length of array instead?

Comment: Do you need the array or only its length?

Comment: I need both array length and its data. I try assigned to `newArr` because I'm not able to access it like this: `for(var i=0; i< <%-arr%>.length; i++){ `

Comment: What is `arr` and what is `food_arr`? Why does `var newArr = <%- arr%>;` and `for(var i=0; i< <%-food_arr%>.length; i++){` not work?

Comment: Apologize for confusion, I copied the wrong thing from my file. What I want is `length of arr` along with its array data.

Answer (score 0):

`newArr` is a string and `newArr.length` is the number of characters. Remove the quotes and stringify the array before:

```
var newArr = <%- JSON.stringify(arr) %>;
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution but it doesn't work...

Comment: Now the length is 0 sir.

Comment: @Omia What's the problem with this code? Please add some debugging details. What's the generated code? Add an example for `arr`.

Comment: After stringify, `newArr.length` will give 0. Or should I get in another way?

Comment: I should get 3 instead.

Comment: @Omia Please add some debugging details. What's the generated code? Add an example for `arr`.

Comment: Hi. Sorry for late reply. Since I'm really not able to get correct length in Javascript, I pushed them to a new normal array first in my controller, then only render ready-to-use arrays to the ejs file, so that I don't have to deal with this issue in ejs....Thanks for trying to guide me.